# Swagger settings to solve mixed content error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a dotnet core web api that is documented by swagger.
Here is how I set it up:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddHealthChecks();
        services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
            options.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetConverter());
            options.Converters.Add(new LabelDataConverter());
            return options;
        });
        services.AddCacheManager(Configuration);
        services.AddKafkaConsumers(Configuration);

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "X.WebApi", Version = "v1" });
        });
        
        services.AddInfluxDb(options => Configuration.GetSection("InfluxDb").Bind(options));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "X.WebApi v1"));

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseHealthChecks("/health");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });            
    }
```

I can run the endpoints by swagger ui on my local machine but when I deploy the application to server I'm getting `TypeError: Failed to fetch` errors. Here is what I see on browser's console:

> swagger-ui-bundle.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://x.y.consul.z.com/swagger/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://x.y.consul.z.com/v1/Path/1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How should I update the swagger settings to be able to run without issue also on the server?

Comment: Make sure your code in `Conifgure` follows this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio  order matters... you have to put the swagger stuff before `UseRouting...`

Comment: @Andy Yes, swagger stuff is just before UseRouting() call.

Comment: i've used swagger/swashbuckle hundreds of times, and have never seen this error. It has to be something with how your `Configure` method is set up. You probably should show all the code in that method.

Comment: @Andy updated the configure method

Comment: can you change the line in `ConfigureServices` to simply `services.AddSwaggerGen();` and run it again. Doubt it will help, but i'm out of ideas. Something is configured to not use HTTPS, and without seeing all the code, I have no idea what it is

Comment: I updated also the `ConfigureServices` method

Comment: @Andy unfortunately `services.AddSwaggerGen();` also ends up with the same result.

Comment: If you are running behind a proxy on your production environment then there is a strong possibility that the firewall/reverse proxy standing in front of dotnet core is configured to offload the ssl traffic. Thus you can end up serving https to the internet but your aspnetcore web app thinks is served using http. The only way to overcome this is through the `app.UseForwardedHeaders();app.UseHttpMethodOverride();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add HTTPS as a scheme to your swagger UI to workaround this issue: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/

Answer (score 0):

When deployed, is your application exposed in HTTPS using a proxy server, load balancer or such?

If it is, then your problem may not be the Swagger itself, but losing the original HTTPS scheme when converting to HTTP. In fact, please check if you are able to call your API.

In this case, the solution may be as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0#troubleshoot). (Please, check this out, as there are some tweaks in the order of the middlewares and such.)

In short, you can try something like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Configure this as suited for your case
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Processing all forward headers (the default is None)
        options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;

        // Clearing known networks and proxies collections
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear(); 
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    // If you only specify this and don't perform the configuration
    // in "ConfigureServices", the default configuration is used
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    // ...
}
```